# Google Sheets: How to find maximum value corresponding to another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to return Exclude/Include text in column D of the attached google sheet on the basis of the following criteria:

- Column C i.e. 'Team Member' contains duplicate values i.e. Team Member names are repetitive i.e. name 'Alice Cook' mentioned in cell C2 can occur any number of times and Column A contains dates. If there are multiple entries for a team member in column C, then I would like to retrieve the text 'Include' in column D in case of the latest date for that team member, else return 'Exclude'.

For example. In case of 'Alice Cook' cell D2 should show 'Exclude' as the latest date for 'Alice Cook' is 8/18/2015 and hence cell D7 will show 'Include'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but this works. Copy this to C2 then copy the formula down.

```
=if(and($A2="",$B2=""),"",if($A2= (ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(if($B$2:$B=$B2,$A$2:$A)))),"Include","Exclude"))
```

It will let you add new data in A & B and C will be blank until data is added (if C is filled down that far)

Answer (score 0):

**Update: single formula**

Here's arrayFormula to paste in `D2`, it'll populate automativally:

```
=ArrayFormula(
if(A2:A9=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(C2;;;counta(A2:A));QUERY(A2:C;"select C, max(A) where C 
<> '' group by C label max(A) ''");2;0);"In";"Ex")
)
```

Please, look at [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_O85VysuKSkQ94ASbu3cuzYFIqC4N1awmnCHUEsYCYg/edit#gid=2040270938).